# How can I debug lxc-create config file?

Tags: lxc

I use `lxc-create -n Test -f t -t busybox` to create a lxc-container on Archlinux, just get an error

> Error creating container Test

nothing else.

The template lxc-busybox comes from the lxc package from ArchLinux. How do I know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the logpriority and logfile options with lxc-create to add more information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

- `lxc-update-config -c /path/to/config` may help fix configuration
  problems if a template is not generating current `lxc` api keywords.
- For a better supported small container option install an Alpine Linux `lxc` container
  (which uses`busybox` for `init`)
- Using the pre-built `download` templates will also give you less
  problems:

`lxc-create -t download -n test`

& choose a supported distribution / version / arch:

```
Distribution: 
alpine
Release: 
3.9
Architecture: 
amd64

Using image from local cache
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created an Alpinelinux 3.9 x86_64 (20190412_13:00) container.

[laptop /srv/lxc]# pacman -Ss lxc

community/lxc 1:3.1.0-1 [installed]
    Linux Containers

[laptop /srv/lxc]# du -h /srv/lxc/test | tail -n 1
9.5M    /srv/lxc/test
```